# ASP.NET Core Kestrel RequestSizeLimit different for different users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, size, kestrel-http-server

In our ASP.NET Core 2.0 app we would like to have a `RequestSizeLimit` of X for most users, but for some special users we'd like to bump it up to a higher value Y > X.

I.e. we have this today:

```
[HttpPost("files")]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string uploadId, IFormCollection formData)
{
    /* Action body */
}
```

But we want to apply a higher size limit for some specific users.

How can this be done?

The app is hosted behind IIS in a reverse proxy setup.

Answer (score 1):

You should write own Attribute and Filter. Try checking in it, which user is authorized, then check request size(you can achieve it by checking `HttpContext`). You can achieve it by impleneting own `IAsyncActionFilter`.

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks! Will mark as correct answer if/when we actually go forward with it and see that it works.

Comment: Any problems? Is this okay solution ?

Comment: Seems like a good idea. We just have other work with higher priority at the moment, so it may take a while (months or more) to get this implemented.